# NSUserDefaults not changing values

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a game with three different game modes and a high score screen each in a different view controller. I'm storing the high scores using `NSUserDefaults` but the values will change throughout the runtime of the application.

The application will save the high scores correctly and when I press clear the scores will all set to 0 and it will show on the screen. If I leave the app and come back the scores will still be zero, but if I replay one of the game modes and return to the high scores screen all the scores will reset to what they where before I cleared them.

Ex: arcade score == 4, easy score == 7, opposite score == 21
I clear the scores and they all are set and show to be zero. Then I play arcade mode and get a score of 6 and return to the high score screen. The values should be (arcade == 6, easy == 0, opposite == 0), but they show to be arcade == 6, easy == 7, opposite == 21.

In one of the GameViewControllers:

```
func lose(){    
    // save score
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var arcade_score = defaults.integerForKey("arcade")
    if(arcade_score < cur+1){                  // cur == current level
        defaults.setInteger(cur+1, forKey: "arcade")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

This method is called whenever the player loses the game. This method is similar in each game controller but stores the value in a different key.

In my HighScoreViewController I load and show the values in the `viewDidLoad()` method and have a button to clear the values:

```
class HighScoreViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var arcade: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var easy: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var opposite: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var arcade_score = defaults.integerForKey("arcade")
        var easy_score = defaults.integerForKey("easy")
        var opposite_score = defaults.integerForKey("opposite")

        arcade.text = String(arcade_score)
        arcade.sizeToFit()
        easy.text = String(easy_score)
        easy.sizeToFit()
        opposite.text = String(opposite_score)
        opposite.sizeToFit()
    }

    @IBAction func clearScores(sender: UIButton) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(0, forKey: "arcade")
        defaults.setInteger(0, forKey: "easy")
        defaults.setInteger(0, forKey: "opposite")
        defaults.synchronize()
        arcade.text = String(defaults.integerForKey("arcade"))
        arcade.sizeToFit()
        easy.text = String(defaults.integerForKey("easy"))
        easy.sizeToFit()
        opposite.text = String(defaults.integerForKey("opposite"))
        opposite.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: @0yeoj changing the declaration to `var` did not fix the problem

Comment: This is not a question about the [tag:xcode] IDE.